# ZeroClipboard - How to use

Tags: javascript, copy, zeroclipboard

I'm using this one http://jonrohan.github.io/ZeroClipboard/

I spent this whole day figuring out how to use ZeroClipboard(ZC). I even read the instructions: https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md
and followed it step by step and couldn't do it.

I tried again and again and again but I just can't get it to work. I even spent hours reading other guides at stackoverflow and other pages both just couldn't get this to work. Moreover, most of the answers are outdated.

Can anyone please write a simple working ZC code that copies a paragraph tag:

```
<p>Hello, I'm Armesh</p>
```

Then just tell me simply each part of the ZC code and why you wrote it that way.

I plan to use ZC to copy references generated by my generator: http://anonoz.com/armesh/

This is the code I wrote, all link references are correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zero Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
</head>

<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  var clip = new ZeroClipboard($("#copy_button"), {
      moviePath: "javascripts/ZeroClipboard.swf"
    });     
});
</script>

<body>
<button id='#copy_button' data-clipboard-target='to_copy'><b>Copy To Clipboard</b></button>

<p id='to_copy'>123456</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I also ran the code/web page above in Google Chrome, there are no errors log in the console. It's blank.

Comment: Can you post some details of what errors you are running into?  There is nothing to go on here.

Comment: Posted a sample code I wrote. Could you please take a look and tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I noticed you put a # in the ID of the button (in the HTML section), any reason for that?

Comment: Thank you sir, I was so frustrated... The examples and API is so confusing

Comment: Is this supported for all browsers ?

Comment: Avoid flash if you can and try this: https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js
Use the /dist/ min file in your page. Demo site code is also in the depo.. ( Simple example: https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/blob/master/demo/constructor-selector.html )

Answer (score 7):

Ok I got it working, I also think the code posted above by me is correct.

The problem was that I was testing on local, and browsers usually prevent flash from running locally. This is what caused it to fail despite the code being correct.

As a last resort, I uploaded to my web server and tried online, it worked fine.

So, always test ZeroClipboard online after uploading it to your Web Server.

Comment: Does it work if you run it through localhost (for example, an XAMPP installation on your local Windows machine (if you're using Windows))?

Comment: Yes, I was using WAMP. It did not work because it was on localhost. So my browser disabled flash which rendered it not working.

Comment: I don't understand, I tried your solution and I have a activated flash and still it is not working. How come that it is possible to use it for online only and not in local computer or test environment?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Bug in your Code!
Look at the button id-attribute and delete the '#' !

And:
If u want more than 1 Clipboard Button on the current Page use the class attribute instead of id.

It works fine now! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can test ZeroClipboard locally by adding the port 3000.
e.g. `http://localhost:3000`